# In the output of lsmeans, is “estimate” is effect size of that contrast?

Tags: r, linear-model, post-hoc

I am using lsmeans to run post-hoc analysis for contrasts of linear mixed model, and here is the output:

```
$contrasts
 contrast            estimate       SE    df t.ratio p.value
 aL2_like - english  450.7397 252.6889 75.99   1.784  0.1819
 aL2_like - thai     224.6113 127.8683 59.66   1.757  0.1931
 english - thai     -226.1284 274.6949 96.77  -0.823  0.6896
```

Can I ask if the estimate here refers to the 'effect size' of each contrast?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Yeahhh!! This is what I want. Thank you very much, Peter Flom. You've saved my life. ^^

Answer (score 4):

I just saw this. It depends on what you mean by "effect size". You do not show the command that created this output, so I can't be sure. It looks like you used "pairwise" option, and if so what you have there are estimates of the differences between each pair of LS means. Many people define effect size as some kind of standardized quantity, and this is NOT what is printed by lsmeans.

Comment: Hi Russ, I use this command: lsmeans(lmer54, pairwise~Language, adjust="tukey"). I'm also thinking of using the effect size from Cohen'd. Which one do you think is better?

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. So it's just LS means and pairwise differences of them. I don't care much for Cohen's $d$ and such, as I like quantities that have units. The `lsmeans` output is in the same units as the response variable. I know that a lot of people in the social sciences like those standardized measures; they're just not of much interest to me.

Comment: Yep, it seems like my colleague strongly recommended me to use it in our paper. I might have to follow his suggestion. Anyway, thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Well, I think all you may need to do is divide the estimated differences by the error SD for the fitted model. (I think R labels it the residual SE).

Comment: Right. I'll try that out. Thanks for all your opinions.